# C++ Macro - pass string and use as a variable name

Tags: c++, macros

So i'm working on a small hobby project which i have implemented a very basic reflection of enums. I have come across an issue which i'm struggling to find a solution.

This would be an ideal call which i'm looking for

```
    Reflect_Value("TestStringName", "StringValue")
```

the first parameter is a string which is intended to be appended onto a variable name and the second to be the actual string value

```
#define Reflect_Value(name,t)   \
namespace Reflection {          \
static ReflectedObject object_##name = ReflectedObject(name,t); }\
```

now the macro would then take that first parameter and be used as object_TestStringName but when i pass the string in the code evaluates to object_"TestStringName" which doesn't compile.

What am i doing wrong here or can anyone provide any solutions to how i could get this functionality please. its important to have the name be something i guess recognisable and also unique so i can reflect many objects

Thanks

Comment: Maybe lose the quotes around TestStringName?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do what you want with the stringification operator `#`:

```
#define Reflect_Value(name,t)   \
namespace Reflection {          \
static ReflectedObject object_##name = ReflectedObject( #name, #t ); }\
```

You'd then call the macro with unquoted arguments:

```
Reflect_Value(TestStringName, StringValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a string, but stringize it:

```
#define stringize(name) #name
#define Reflect_Value(name,t)   \
namespace Reflection {          \
static ReflectedObject object_##name = ReflectedObject(stringize (name),t); }
```

Then:

```
Reflect_Value(TestStringName, "StringValue")
```

Comment: Honest question: when do you actually need the `stringize` macro, instead of just the stringification operator `#`? Is it just when there's a chance that `name` is itself a macro and not a literal, or is it necessary in general?